# Javascript redirect within Facebook app iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to do a redirect via JS within an FB app in an iframe and it's busting out of the iframe.

Currently it looks like this:

```
window.location.href = '/bla'
```

But this is busting out of the iframe. How do I ensure the redirect occurs, but only within the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Try wit this:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
self.location.href='/bla';
```